# Set selected drop down value from database in razor view MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller, html.dropdownlistfor

I am explicitly creating a dropdownlist in razor mvc view. I would like the default option to be one of the items, the value of that item should come from database

View Code

```
<div class="form-group">
  @Html.LabelFor(model => model[i].Customer.HomeType, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="SerivcesRegistrationInput col-md-10">
      @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model[i].Customer.HomeType, new List<SelectListItem>
 {
     new SelectListItem{ Text="House", Value = "House",@(Model[i].CustomerServices.HomeType == "House" ? Selected = true : false)  },
     new SelectListItem{ Text="Apartment", Value = "Apartment" },
     new SelectListItem{ Text="Farm", Value = "Farm" } },
      "Select your home type", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
 }         
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller Code

```
 cs.HomeType = serviceDetails.HomeType;
 sp.CustomerServices = cs;
 return View("EditCustomerServices", ProviderList);
```

Model has the data I need but how can I set it to correct Dropdown list value. I tried using short hand if but it gives me an error

```
Invalid member initializer
```

Can I add if condition for Selected Boolean?

Comment: why do you use indexer for model -> model[i]

Comment: Because I am running this in loop

Answer (score 0):

```cs
@{
    var selected = Model.CustomerServices.HomeType == "House";
}

<div class="form-group">
  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Customer.HomeType, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="SerivcesRegistrationInput col-md-10">
      @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Customer.HomeType, new List<SelectListItem>
 {
     new SelectListItem{ Text="House", Value = "House", Selected = selected },
     new SelectListItem{ Text="Apartment", Value = "Apartment" },
     new SelectListItem{ Text="Farm", Value = "Farm" } },
      "Select your home type", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
 }         
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What if apartment is selected, there will be too many if conditions. This is not a good way of doing it

Comment: your view model must contain the info about selected item. You should not decide which item is selected in the view, this must be done in the controller.

Comment: how does your model look like?